# insert HTML select option value into mysql table not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to send an option value(from `HTML` select tag) into `MySQL` table.I test every methods,but not success.When I echo option value,value print on screen.But not insert into database.Anybody know a solution?
This is my code :

```
<select class="input" name="selector">
              <option value="student">a</option>
              <option value="director">b</option>
              <option value="master">c</option>
              <option value="education">d</option>
            </select>

<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $serveruser = "root";
        $serverpassword = "";
        $db_name = "university";
        //
        $selector = $_POST["selector"];
        //
        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            $sqlconnection = new MySQLi($servername,$serveruser,$serverpassword,$db_name);
            if (!$sqlconnection)
             {
              die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
             }
            $query="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$selector')";
            mysqli_set_charset($sqlconnection,"utf8");
            mysqli_query($sqlconnection,$query);
            mysqli_close($sqlconnection);
            //
            echo($selector);

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you get an error? Did you check the result of `mysqli_query` and the details in `mysqli_error` if it indicated failure? On a side note: Are you aware of your vulnerability to SQL injection? That insert statement will always fail if `users` has more than one column.

Comment: thanks.yes,I know.but there is no error returned.for 'users' table I'm using this with column name,as "users (usage)".

Comment: There is no error returned because you don't seem to check it. For starters, `mysqli_query` returns a boolean.

Comment: but when Im using another $_POST variable (input tags) it works fine.only select option value has problem.

Comment: Use mysqli_query(..) or die(mysql_error())   will give you the error

Comment: oh!yes,I tested it now. mysqli_query returns false value.

Comment: you have some missing parts

Comment: what parts missing??

Comment: thanks dear Golez trol.i made it!alter table and create it again.thank you friends!

Answer (score 3):

your problem is here

```
$query="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$selector')";
```

when you run that query, the database engine has NO idea what values go where.
try something like this instead

```
$query="INSERT INTO users('column_name') VALUES('$selector')";
```

I don't know your table structure, but in an insert query, you have to tell it WHAT you are inserting, as well as WHERE you are inserting it.